# Matplotlib plot does not display

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter

Am I supposed to include something else here? And what is the purpose of these '>> 'and '<< ’ symbols? Am I supposed to include them anywhere?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

plt.xlabel (‘Sepal Length’)
plt.ylabel(‘Petal Length’)
plt.title(‘Sepal vs Petal Length’)
plt.scatter(data[SepalLength], data[PetalLength], c= b)
```

Comment: Which symbols are you referring to?

Comment: "<< " ">>" Bit shifters. Do i need to add them?

Comment: Should not be necessary in this case, as far as I understand. They're useful for bit manipulation, but this is not necessary to create a plot

Comment: This would be easer to advise on if you posted a complete minimal reproducible example. Because those advising you just need `plt.show()` aren't necessarily right but they aren't for sure right either. A lot also depends on how up to date your environment and Jupyter is. If it was up-to-date, both in Jupyter notebook and JupyterLab, you shouldn't need the `plt.show()` for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just missing the `plt.show()` at the end to display the plot.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you have written expects to plot it.
just add `plt.show()`

Answer (score -1):

This is to follow-up my comment below the OP that while others were suggesting the lack of `plt.show()` was the issue, that isn't necessarily 100% cut-and-dry.
The following will work with no additional code in notebooks launched from [here](https://github.com/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder) by going to https://github.com/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder and pressing `launch binder`:

```py
!curl -OL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("iris.csv")
plt.xlabel ('Sepal Length')
plt.ylabel('Petal Length')
plt.title('Sepal vs Petal Length')
plt.scatter(data["sepal_length"], data["petal_length"], c= 'b');
```

When the notebook that comes up upon launch opens, you can make a new cell and paste that code in and run that cell.

Note that you don't need the traditional `plt.show()`. Modern Jupyter and matplotlib work together well, and so Jupyter tries to show the plot figure that was made without requiring `plt.show()`.

**If adding `plt.show()` works that may be all you need in your case; however, you may want to know that you shouldn't need it.**

So the fact it isn't displaying when you run similar code may mean your environment just has something that isn't quite up-to-date or is mismatched. It happens. That is why environments are a better way to manage things if you aren't using them already. That way you can update things more regularly and not mess up running your other code.

---

More details on the posted code and supplied link for launching sessions in your browser for those interested:
The provided code works in both the classic notebook interface and JupyterLab in sessions launched from the link provided. You can switch to the JupyterLab interface from a session already launched from [that link](https://github.com/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder) by clicking on the Jupyter icon on the upper left corner of the notebook that comes up at the start. You can then open a new notebook from the JupyterLab launcher and try this again in this interface. Go back to the classic notebook interface from the menu above the notebook using `Help` > `Launch Classic Notebook`.