# Can't plot inline in iPython shell (Terminal and VScode terminal window)

Tags: matplotlib, visual-studio-code, ipython

can anyone help me to understand, why my ***iPython shell*** does ***not plot inline*** and in an external window instead? I am *not talking about Jupyter notebooks*. I made that work. Any help is appreciated and highly welcome. Thank you ...

Of course I tried several sources to tackle my issues.

- Stackoverflow: -> didn't work
- matplotlib.org -> same
- ipython docs -> same
- several others suggested by Google -> same

```
(py310_env) Murat ~ % ipython                   
Python 3.10.0 (default, Nov 10 2021, 11:24:47) [Clang 12.0.0 ]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.1.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

The following code will plot, but **not inline**:

In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [2]: import numpy

In [3]: %matplotlib
Using matplotlib backend: MacOSX

In [4]: plt.plot([0,1,4,9,16])
Out[4]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f7821f3cfa0>]
```

I also tried this statement:

```
`%matplotlib inline´
```

if I try this one, then I get the following and not even an external display of the plot.

```
In [6]: plt.plot([0,1,4,9,16])
Out[6]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f7823002020>]
<Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes>
```

I thought, that maybe my backend needs to be changed so. I tried I couldn`t even change it.

```
In [8]: %matplotlib qt
Warning: Cannot change to a different GUI toolkit: qt. Using osx instead.

In [9]: matplotlib tk
Warning: Cannot change to a different GUI toolkit: tk. Using osx instead.
```

Comment: The ipython console is a text based interface and so you cannot plot inline. That's why you have to go to an external window. `%matplotlib inline` is for [Jupyter](http://mybinder.org/v2/gh/binder-examples/requirements/master), which grew out of the IPython notebook project. Actually for modern Jupyter it is no longer necessary to specify as it generally defaults to plotting any matplotlib plot inline, see [here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71530442/8508004). Note I don't have `%matplotlib inline` and the posted code works as described.

Comment: I should point to [the documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/plotting.html#id1): "... the inline backend. This is available only for the Jupyter Notebook and the Jupyter QtConsole."

Comment: There is a new option that allows a REPL behavior and ipython shell-like look that plots in line by default. See it demonstrated [here](https://youtu.be/-_i1JTRnlXc?t=1936). In that example Jermy is using the Pyolite REPL you'll presently see under 'Try NumPy' at [the Numpy.org main page](https://numpy.org/). He pastes in matplotlib & plotly code and gets both in line by default. You can find the code he pastes in [here](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_static/lab/), the matplotlib example is in the `python` notebook at the top level & the `plotly` one in the `pyolite` directory.

Comment: For completeness sake, the demo he has open in the other tab actually comes from [here](https://github.com/jupyterlite/demo). You can click to open that under 'Try it in your browser.' A similar demo and more is available at [the main Jupyterlite page](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The link in my last comment actually opens the JupyterLab demo from there. You can see you can launch the REPL variation from there, too.

Comment: Wayne, thank you for the excellent background information, resources and support. So basically my reasoning to use PyQT or Spyder was/is the right way. Now I understand why ("...txt based interface"). My intention was to have all panes VS-Code, while following a certain tutorial on edX. I will "Try it" for sure, just had a quick glance at the videos you linked and it seems interesting. Thank you again ...

Comment: Yes, your reasoning ended up heading in the right direction. I was mostly trying to address your initial query of "can anyone help me to understand, why my iPython shell does not plot inline and in an external window instead?"

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone suggests a better solution, here is my cure.

Initially I had been trying to invoke ipython in the CLI using the command `%ipython`.

My conclusion is now, you need to use `Jupyter Qt-console` (available in the Anaconda distro. (Spyder, Jupyter and PyQT are preinstalled)

`%jupyter qtconsole` : QT will open up Terminal style console for Python and it does the inline plot magic.